# Update the records of a TIMESTAMP field by adding 5 years

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a date field of type TIMESTAMP registered in the database. These values ​​are already filled in. I would like to add 5 years to the current value of each of the records.

For example, if the first record has a date of 05/22/2018, it must go to 05/22/2023.

Each record has a different date, so even years are not common.

Some help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET `your_date_column` = DATE_ADD(`your_date_column` , INTERVAL 5 YEAR) ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4348737aea1acb655cc77c8d9582c176

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INTERVAL`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DAT(dt datetime)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO DAT VALUES('2018-02-02'),('2016-02-02'),('2022-02-02')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE DAT SET dt = dt + INTERVAL 5 YEAR
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM DAT
> ```
>
> ```
> | dt                  |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 |
> | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 |
> | 2027-02-02 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ccd1710f65a73ccf771d43c945f221d)*